# Facebook Send Dialog cannot show the preview image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to use the Facebook SendDialog to send a picture to my friend.
There are a lot of pictures on my app,if user select one picture,My app will create a HTML,
and update the HTML mate tag to:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567890" />
<meta property="og:type" content="momantest:picture" />
<meta property="og:url" content="myhostdomain.com" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Mytitle" />
<meta property="og:description" content="BlahBlah123!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="The picture use just selected" />
```

And save this HTML,named test1.html and upload it to my server.

and I use JSSDK:

```
FB.ui({
       method:'send',
       link : 'https://myhostdomail.com/test1.html'
    });
```

And the SendDialog cannot show the preview picture !!!!!

[image]

But if test1.html create five minutes ago, and then I use senddialog..The preview picture shows...

[image]

So,The problem is ,If I Create a HTML just few seconds and use SendDialog ,the preview picture cannot show,But if the HTML is already created for 5mins ago,and use SendDialog,the preview picture shows...

Why is that ? Is this a bug ?

Is it possible that the SendDialog can show the preview picture when the HTML just created few seconds ago!

**Oh,right, I also used object debbug tool to check the url, it responsed 206, title, decription and image , all fine.. But Send Dialog just cannot show the preview picture**

Any answer would be appreciated. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are overwriting the Meta tags every time someone wants to send an image, this won't work as Facebook caches the meta data when the link is first shared.

What you need to do is use unique URLs for each share so the data stays intact and unique to that share. For example:

1. `User 1` wants to share `image1.jpg`. Then create `share1.html` and add appropriate meta data for this share.
2. Then, when `User 1` wants to share `image2.jpg`. You create `share2.html` with new meta data, and share this instead.
3. If `User 2` wants to also share `image1.jpg`, you can reuse `share1.html`, as the meta data will be the same.

Comment: I knew about the Facebook caches, So when I create the HTML, I add the random number to every HTML,eg:test1.html?v=231412, and it worked.. Funny is, when I use the Share Dialog, the preview picture showed.... !!!! Just Send Dialog, preview picture couldn't show ~ It's drove me crazy ! Thanks for your answer anyway ~!

Comment: By the way, if user1 select a picture, it will create test1.html?v=123 image is image1.jpg     if user2 select,create test2.html?v=432 , image2.jpg, It's unique URL for every HTML to every user , So, I don't think it's the caches problem  :D

Comment: Ah, the Share Dialog won't show the preview unless you manually add it using the `picture` parameter.